# I can't get an image to load on the canvas in Tkinter python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am having a big issue. The Canvas loads perfectly but the image does not display.

I started Python 1 week ago and I have no clue why does is not working. Can anyone please show me the way to solve the issue of the image not loading on the canvas?

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

class Fake_Virus:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Totally not a virus!")

        b = Button(master, text="Help", command=self.prank)
        b.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=LEFT)

        quit = Button(master, text="Close", command=self.close_window)
        quit.pack(padx=10, pady=10, side=RIGHT)




        photo = PhotoImage("eh.gif")

        label = Label(image=photo)
        label.image = photo # keep a reference!
        label.pack()



        f = Frame(master, height=150, width=150)
        f.pack_propagate(0) # don't shrink
        f.pack()

    def prank(self):
        print "work"
        return

    def close_window(self):
        root.destroy()
        return


root = Tk()
my_gui = Fake_Virus(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `file` option to initialize the photo image object.
This means you need to change `photo = PhotoImage("eh.gif")` to `photo = PhotoImage(file="eh.gif")`

Now your code will work. But a working code is not necessarily a good code. There are other issues with your code. Let me go through them quickly:

- It is better to code `import Tkinter as Tk` than `from Tkinter import *`
- Why that hyphen in your class name? Follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) so that, in the futur, people will find it easy to review and understand your code.
- Good that you have written `self.master = master` (read [complete code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) to know why) but then you have never used it. This means you made a good decision and you render it useless.
- You set the title of the window within the initializer. It is better if you do that in a separate function so that whenever you want to add additional settings to your GUI (such as the size, font or whatever) you will only add code to that function instead of vomiting lot of trash inside the initializer which rather needs to be clean.
- None of the widgets you created is '*selfed*' (you may read [*Why explicit self has to stay*](http://neopythonic.blogspot.fi/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html))
- It is better you create the widgets in a separate function otherwise your `__init__()` will be dirty.
- Why do you use return in `prank()` and `close_window()`? By default, Python functions that do not return something return `None` anyway so it is useless to code that.
- Why did you pack one button to left and the other one to right and then no pack siding for the label? Read about the [pack()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) geometry manager.
- Why you did not attach the label to a parent widget as you did for the 2 other buttons? All Tkinter widgets need to be clung into a parent widget. The grand parent of those widgets is an instance of `Tkinter.Tk()`
- Why did you create that frame and then you never used it? You are not doing anything with it, so ..?

Given these remarks, I want to provide you an improved -but not perfect- version of your program. You can then follow this 'philosophy' to add or modifying existing widgets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as Tk
from PIL import ImageTk

class FakeVirus:
   def __init__(self, master):
       self.master = master
       self.configure_gui()
       self.create_widgets()

   def configure_gui(self):
       self.master.title('Totally not a virus!')

   def create_widgets(self):
       self.create_buttons()
       self.create_label_for_image()

   def create_buttons(self):
       self.help = Tk.Button(self.master, text='Help', command=self.prank)
       self.help.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
       self.quit = Tk.Button(self.master, text='Close', command=self.close_window)
       self.quit.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

   def create_label_for_image(self):
       self.image_label = Tk.Label(self.master)
       self.image_label.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
       self.load_image_to_label()

   def load_image_to_label(self):
       self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='eh.gif')
       self.image_label.image = self.photo
       self.image_label.config(image=self.photo)

   def prank(self):
       print "work"

   def close_window(self):
        root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk.Tk()
   my_gui = FakeVirus(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

The output of the above program is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for improving my code. Like I said I picked up on python 3 weeks ago so i have really sloppy code